NumericUpDown getting reset to minimum value when clicked
I have NumericeUpdown embedded inside an EditingListView column in a Windows desktop application. The ListView will show decimal value as text and when clicked, the NumericUpDown should be visible with the decimal value in it so that the user can edit it. But when the user clicks on the cell, the NumericUpDown control is showing with value "0.00"
// Inside Constructor
lvUpdates.SetEditableColumn(FinalizeAmountColumn, EditingListViewEditType.NumericUpDown);

// Event handlers

private void lvUpdates_ControlShowing(object sender, CancelEditingListViewEventArgs e)
    {
        var lvi = (PropertyListViewItem)lvUpdates.Items[e.Row];
        if (lvi == null)
            return;

        var info = (DebtSetOffMatchUpdateInformation)lvi.Tag;
        if (info.MatchAmount <= 0 || info.RecordType != DebtSetOffMatchUpdateInformation.RecordTypes.Finalize)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        if (e.Column == FinalizeAmountColumn && e.Control is NumericUpDown nud)
        {
            nud.Minimum = 0;
            nud.Maximum = info.MatchAmount;
            nud.DecimalPlaces = 2;

            var sValue = lvi.SubItems[FinalizeAmountColumn].Text;
            if (!sValue.HasValue())
                sValue = "0.00";
            nud.Value = decimal.Parse(sValue, NumberStyles.Any);
            nud.Text = sValue;
            nud.Refresh();
        }
    }


if (!sValue.HasValue()) Does it have a value there, when you expect one?

Yes. The values are getting set correctly.  I have verified it by debugging. But once I continue from debugging and see the application,  the NumericUpDown control will be in edit mode with value 0.00

Why are setting both the .Value and the .Text? Why are you calling .Refresh() after? -- What kind of ListView is that? Why have you tagged the question with both winforms and asp.net? Remove the irrelevant tag

@Jimi I was trying to set all the properties to cover all the scenarios. Refresh() is called to update the control in UI. The ListView is a EditingListView
This is a windows desktop app, that is why tagged winforms

@Fildor please see my comment

That's not a common Control, not a standard one anyway, so first thing replace all var with the actual Type. For example, what is this: var sValue = lvi.SubItems[FinalizeAmountColumn].Text;, then this: !sValue.HasValue()? -- With a NumericUpDown, just set the .Value, remove Refresh()

@Jimi I tried what you suggested, but the behavior is still the same. And JFYI, I can see the value is getting set correctly when I debug and the Value property is correctly showing as updated. But ultimately in UI, it is showing the control in edit mode with value 0.00 in it

As mentioned, this custom Control has of course its own behavior, which is probably unknown to most people. At least, I've never used or, actually, seen it. You should provide all the relevant debugging information. For example, I don't know what happens in the ControlShowing event handler (is the Control already created? Does it have its Handle?) -- As also mentioned, edit the question to show the Types used. I can assume .HasValue() is an extension method, applied to string, you made. But nobody wants to assume anything. You must provide this information (and the implementation) ...

... It's also not clear why you're parsing the value as string, when it looks like you're taking some other data from a strongly typed class object

I finally resolved the problem by replacing the custom event handler with the MouseClick handler. For reference, I'm posting the solution in case anyone faces similar issues with custom controls and wants to explore other event handlers.
private void lvUpdates_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hitTestInfo = lvUpdates.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        var lvItem = hitTestInfo.Item;
        var columnIndex = hitTestInfo.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hitTestInfo.SubItem);
        var info = (DebtSetOffMatchUpdateInformation)lvItem.Tag;
        if (info.MatchAmount <= 0 || info.RecordType != DebtSetOffMatchUpdateInformation.RecordTypes.Finalize)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (columnIndex == FinalizeAmountColumn)
        {
            NumericUpDown nud = new NumericUpDown
            {
                Minimum = 0,
                Maximum = info.CurrentBalance < info.MatchAmount ? info.CurrentBalance : info.MatchAmount,
                DecimalPlaces = 2
            };

            if (decimal.TryParse(lvItem.SubItems[columnIndex].Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var currentValue)) nud.Value = currentValue;
            else nud.Value = 0.00M;

            // Position and show the NumericUpDown control
            nud.Bounds = hitTestInfo.SubItem.Bounds;
            nud.Leave += (s, ev) =>
            {
                // When leaving the control, make sure we display the result in money format in ListView
                var newAmount = nud.Value;
                lvItem.SubItems[columnIndex].Text = newAmount == 0 ? string.Empty : Globals.FormatCurrency(newAmount);
                lvUpdates.Controls.Remove(nud); // Remove the NumericUpDown control after editing
            };

            lvUpdates.Controls.Add(nud);
            nud.Focus();
        }
    }

